# Google Picker not selecting by file extension

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

Given files in Drive with an (arbitrary) extension *.abc, this code...

```
gapi.load("picker", { "callback": function () {
    if (!picker) {
        var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);

        view.setMimeTypes("application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.abc");

        view.setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST);
        picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();
        picker.setTitle(TEXT.PICKER_PROMPT);
        picker.setAppId(CONST.APP_ID);
        picker.addView(view);
        picker.setOAuthToken(session.OAuthToken.access_token);
        picker.setCallback(pickerCallback);
        picker.setInitialView(view);
    };
    picker.build().setVisible(true);
));
```

...doesn't find any of the existing 'abc' files in drive. 
These files are of mime type text/xml, and the following line DOES find them:

```
view.setMimeTypes("text/xml");
```

Why doesn't the search by extension work?

Comment: I think it makes sense that it doesn't work with extensions since the function sets the mime types and not extensions. In drive you can find that every file has a mime type, but it is not the same for extensions, you can have files without extensions. This is easier to see with native Google files (Spreadsheets, docs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those finding this from Google, the question wasn't as daft as it sounded - there *is* a (pseudo) mime-type for each extension in the Drive world, but it's not usable in that way, at least not in the Picker.

A workable (ie user-friendly) solution is to use a query on the view:

```
view.setQuery("*.abc");
```

For completeness:

```
gapi.load("picker", { "callback": function () {
    if (!picker) {
        var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);

        view.setMimeTypes("text/xml");
        view.setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST);
        view.setQuery("*.abc");

        picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();
        picker.setTitle(TEXT.PICKER_PROMPT);
        picker.setAppId(CONST.APP_ID);
        picker.addView(view);
        picker.setOAuthToken(session.OAuthToken.access_token);
        picker.setCallback(pickerCallback);
        picker.setInitialView(view);
    };
    picker.build().setVisible(true);
));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was trying to find out how to use `setQuery` in a view and this code explained everything quite nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to HeyHeyJC's answer, you can use a double pipe (`||`) separating each file extension, if you want to use multiple.

For example, `view.setQuery("*.abc || *.def || *.ghi");`